# Computer losing wired connection for a couple seconds and reconnects

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I've recently been experiencing an issue that's most noticeable while I am playing games. The ethernet is losing connection for a couple seconds and reconnecting (The ethernet icon on the bottom right shows a red X for a couple seconds and my game freezes). It happens sporadically and I am not sure what is causing the problem.

Here are the things I have tried:

1. Updated BIOS

   2. Updated Ethernet Drivers
   3. Tried both ethernet ports on the motherboard.
   4. Restarted computer, router, and modem.
   5. Updated router firmware.
   6. Run full virus scan

Anybody have any idea?

PC:
Win 10 64 bit
Ethernet Intel & Killer ethernet

Router: UniFi USG

Model: Arris 8100

The connection from my pc: -> Unmanaged Switch -> Router

Comment: Have you tried changing (or removing) the switch? The physical L1 link is between your PC and what's immediately connected to it – right now that's the switch, not the router, not the modem. (Post your own answer if that helps.)

Comment: The network connection flicking can have a lot of reasons. In most cases I have seen the reasons were: bad patchcord, bad contacts, NIC damage. And in some cases the connection speed fixing helps.

Comment: It shows a red 'X', and does it say "Cable unplugged"?

Comment: Agree with @akina & grawity. Try new patch cables, & inspect the pins on your nics.

Comment: @Akina it replaced the patch cord. Seems to have solved the issue. Feel free to post an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The network connection flicking can have a lot of reasons. In most cases I have seen the reasons were:

- bad patchcord (replace it)
- bad contacts (clean and straighten them)
- NIC damage (replace it or, if it is on-board, disable it and add new discrete one)

And in some cases the connection speed fixing (remove auto-negotiation from NIC and/or commutator port settings) helps.